# Build Chromium webui test without rebuilding all browser_tests

Tags: integration-testing, chromium, ninja

I added a simple JavaScript test to `/src/chrome/test/data/webui/` and included the file in `/src/chrome/chrome_tests.gypi`.

I built it like this: `ninja -C out/Debug browser_tests`. That takes a while though. Is there a way to rebuild my test only, without also building all the other browser tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

browser_tests is the only executable target to compile those tests so you need to use it in any case even if you perform a change in a single test. But you may want to try shared library compilation to improve the speed of your builds. For that just `export GYP_DEFINES='component=shared_library'` and then `./build/gyp_chromium` before recompiling.

Comment: Thanks! I found that solution the other day, but hadn't got round to mention it here yet. I did it like this `build/gyp_chromium -D component=shared_library` which I guess is just a slightly different way of doing the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

<sup>NOTE: This answer is **not** applicable to webui tests (they do not depend on `test_data_dir_`. Further, it is only relevant to Linux.</sup>

Some test files is not compiled into `browser_tests`. For these cases, just set the `CR_SOURCE_ROOT` environment variable to the Chromium source directory, e.g. (if your Chromium source files are located at `~/chromium/src`)

```
CR_SOURCE_ROOT=~/chromium/src/ ./out/Debug/browser_tests
```

I discovered this when I tried to figure out why the extension tests did not run. I started with looking up the error message in the source code:

> Extension error: Could not load extension from ''. Manifest file is missing or unreadable.

After some debugging with gdb, I found that the test extension that is supposed to be loaded by [`ExtensionBrowserTest::LoadExtensionWithFlags`](https://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/browser/extensions/extension_browsertest.cc?revision=247788#l126) did not load because the path was invalid. `path` was somehow set to `"extensions/api_test/webrequest"`, and because this is not an absolute path, it was cleared in [`UnpackedInstaller::GetAbsolutePath`](https://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/browser/extensions/unpacked_installer.cc?revision=246373#l218) by `extension_path_ = base::MakeAbsoluteFilePath(extension_path_);`.
Consequently, Chromium tries to load an extension from location "" (empty string), which obviously fails.

Ultimately, I tracked down the cause to `test_data_dir_`, which is initialized at [`DIR_TEST_DATA`](https://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/browser/chromeos/policy/user_cloud_external_data_manager_browsertest.cc?revision=239399#l53), which in turn is [derived from `DIR_SOURCE_ROOT`](https://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/common/chrome_paths.cc?revision=246561#l421), which in turn is [read from the `CR_SOURCE_ROOT` environment variable](https://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/base/base_paths_posix.cc?revision=238144#l76). With the following command, my tests ran again, and I was able to update the extension tests without recompiling.

```
CR_SOURCE_ROOT=~/chromium/src/ ./out/Debug/browser_tests
```